# post all photo from database (auction system)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I currently writing an auction system for my final year project college. I am not sure how to display multiple photos from the database.

Here the sample display; http://www.pennyauction.com.my/

I want to show the photo and when the user clicks on the photo I will transfer to the page for bidding.

Comment: Your photos have to be addressable from your webpage (meaning they need a real address to access them). You could either save the files out to a temporary location from the database to a disk location relative to your site root, or add a hook in your code behind that is referenced from your page that reads the photos directly out of the database.

Comment: I do not want to manually address the photo ( keep modify the coding)
My idea is when a Auction master add an item, the item will automatically post in the site, where I do not need to add the item in coding my own

Comment: He didn't say you have to manually address it. Just save the picture in a web folder and (automatically) give it a unique name, and save the name in the database. Or pull direct from database as M.Babcock also describes.

Answer (score 0):

If this was a real application I'd use Amazon S3 or another CDN to store the images. Since it's just a project, my recommendation is to use the file system.

Since you'll know the `Id` of the item whose photo you want to display, just have your application name the files with that `Id` while you're saving them. This way you can write code like this to show the image:

```
<% var imagesRoot = "http://www.mysite.com/content/user-content/"; %>
<img src = '<%: imagesRoot + model.Id %>' />
```

I've made a huge assumption that you're using ASP .NET, and that `model` would be a view model class for your item. Any other scripting languages can easily do the same sort of thing. There's really no reason to keep image files in a database. You can't query against them or do any other interesting things that an RDBMS is good at (i.e. set-based operations).